# Align divs with same class horizontal

Tags: css

In the past I used float to align my divs horizontal, however now that I'm producing multiple divs with the same "class", float no longer align them horizontal.

If I set position to absolute, they stack on top of each other. 
If I set position to relative, they become vertical aligned.

I can't seem to grasp how to fix this, since they have the same class.

Here is my output:

```
<div class="group">

<div class = "user2">title1</div><div class = "user1">title3</div> 
 <div class = "user2">title2</div><div class = "user1">title4</div> .     <div class="line1">line1<br></div><div class="line2">line2<br> .     </div>
  </div>
```

I want "titles" aligned vertical for each other.

So, user 1 div has: title 1 - tilte 2 
user 2 div has: title 3 - title 4

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: flex` to the class `group`.

```
.group {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

And for its children:

```
.group > div {
    display: flex;
}
```

By default, element with `flex` enabled will force its children to stay in the same `row`.

I strongly recommend you to learn `flexbox` and all its configuration and properties. Here is a great [font](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Looking through the guide for 30 mins now, I can now make them horizontal using flex, however all titles are now on same line. 

I want all titles for user 1 to be on one horizontal line, and a "new" horizontal line for all titles relating to user 2.